# How to store a lot of data in a many-to-many relationship? rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Good people, I'm doing an administrative system in rails 5, and I'm going through the permitting part, basically I want a user to have many groups, and many groups have many users, I know it's a has_many through relationship, I know how to pair from console, but I only know how to take a user and a group, for example:

```
user = User.create name: "Luis", email: "example@email.com"
group = Group.create name: "Development", description: "Those that get screwed thanks to the design >:v"
group2 = Group.create name: "Design", description: "The creatives"
grupo3 = Group.create name: "Ventas", description: "The annoying bugs that only think about making money overnight"
membership = Membership.create group: group, user: user
```

The controllers are basic scaffolds without any addition, and users are registered by means of devise

I want the administrator when creating a group to manage their users and vice versa, when creating a user administer their groups.

I do not want an administrator to have to mark a group at a time, but from the view select several groups (development, design, recruitment), and that rails save them all at once. Nor that you registered the same user several times with different groups that may exist.

Comment: Sounds like accepts_nested_attributes_for might be what you are looking for.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be plenty of syntax errors as I have not tested it, but you can get the idea and correct it.

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

Group Model

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Membership Model

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

UsersController

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id]) 
  @allGroups = Group.all                
  @groupsTheUserIsMember = @user.groups.pluck(:id)
end

def update
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @user.memberships.destroy_all
  #params includes the list of group_ids that will be associated to the user
  params[:group_ids].each do |group_id|
    membership=Membership.create(user_id: @user.id, group_id: group_id)
  end
end
```

GroupsController

```
def edit
  @group = Group.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @allUsers = User.all
  @usersTheGroupIncludes = @group.users.pluck(:id)
end

def update
  @group = Group.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @group.memberships.destroy_all
  #params includes the list of user_ids that will be associated to the group
  params[:user_ids].each do |user_id|
    membership=Membership.create(user_id: user_id, group_id: @group.id)
  end
end
```

views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <h2>Groups</h2>
  <p>Select the groups where the user is member</p>
  <table>
    <%= render 'groups/groups_header' %>
    <%= render partial: 'groups/groups', collection: @allGroups, as: :group, locals: { user_id: @user.id } %>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

views/groups/edit.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@group) do |f| %>
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <p>Select the users that belong to the group</p>
  <table>
    <%= render 'users/users_header' %>
    <%= render partial: 'users/users', collection: @allUsers, as: :user, locals: { group: @group.id } %>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

views/groups/_groups.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- check box to include or remove the group -->
    <% if @usersTheGroupIncludes.include?(user_id) %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', user_id, checked: true %>
    <% else %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', user_id %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
  <td>Group: <%= group.name %></td>
</tr>
```

views/users/_users.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- check box to include or remove the user -->
    <% if @groupsTheUserIsMember.include?(group_id) %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'group_ids[]', group_id, checked: true %>
    <% else %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'group_ids[]', group_id %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
  <td>User: <%= user.name %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I created the development group from the view. But he says he can not go through the group_ids because it's empty, but from the view (when creating a user) I frame the group_ids.

The code is this: <% = form.collection_check_boxes: group_ids, Group.order (: name),: id,: name, id:: user_group_id%>

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Which line of code shows the error? My solutions only creates Memberships (you cannot create the development group with my code). It only relates a User with many Groups (or a Group with many Users). But users and groups must already be created. I thought this was already done by yourself.

Comment: Sorry. I explain better. I created a group called "development", all is fine with that. But when I try to update an user to assing the group "development", I can't, it says that params[:group_ids] is null, so it can not be iterated (in your code `params[:group_ids].each do |group_id|`). But I marked the development group at the user update view.

Comment: I think you put the groups_ids (and users_ids) inside the form (using form.collection_check_boxes) and this is not how I did it. That's why the group_ids must be inside params[user]. Maybe you should use params[user][:group_ids].each do |group_id|.  Can you show the params passed to UsersControllers#update (from the log)?

Comment: `NoMethodError in UsersController#update
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`                                                        And the line with error is: `params[@user][:group_ids].each do |group_id|`  But when I see the console, i can see that `"user"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com", "group_ids"=>["", "1"]}`

Comment: It's params[:user][:groups_ids]

Comment: That gave an error: `undefined local variable or method 'user' for #<UsersController:0xb40e306c> Did you mean? @user`

Comment: Where are you getting the error? I don't think I have used a variable or method 'user' at the update method in UsersController. The new sentence I wrote was:  params[:user][:group_ids].each do |group_id|  (check the colon before user ":")

Comment: But why I need params[:user][:group_ids]? I want to know what I'm saying to rails with that

Comment: All parameters passed to the controller are inside the hash params. If the form is built using form_for @user, all params are in the hash params, and the params from the form are inside params[:user]. That’s how form_for builds the html form. It’s useful to get all params togheter. If it works, please accept the answer :). Regards.